# Unix: Extract contents from a line correctly

Tags: unix, awk, grep, cut

We have several lines as below:

```
ghselm|Linka|Alzelmo|BJKSKJ|SK1234|adm-approved-email*adm-approved-kmart*adm-approved-sears2*arb-user*fls-buyer*impt-user*mch-kminvmgmt*mdm-inventoryanalyst*pac_eligible*res-astpln-genacc*shc-shc-assoc*shc-shc-corp*sig-preview*sys-has-email*sys-has-kmart*sys-has-sears2*vpn-remoteaccess*adm-approved-email*adm-approved-kmart*adm-approved-sears2*arb-user*fls-buyer*impt-user*mch-kminvmgmt*mch-vpppfl*mdm-inventoryanalyst*pac_eligible*res-astpln-genacc*shc-shc-assoc*shc-shc-corp*sig-preview*mch-ga*sys-has-email*sys-has-kmart*sys-has-sears2*vpn-remoteaccess|
```

We need to have a script which can give us the data as below with only mch type data:

```
ghselm|Linka|Alzelmo|BJKSKJ|SK1234|mch-kminvmgmt*mch-kminvmgmt*mch-vpppfl*mch-ga|
```

Comment: awk -F'mch-' '{ print $2 }' but it did not help.

Answer (score 1):

This could be done through Perl.

```
$ perl -pe 's/[^|]*?(\*mch-\w+).*?(?=\*mch|\|)/\1/g' file
ghselm|Linka|Alzelmo|BJKSKJ|SK1234|*mch-kminvmgmt*mch-kminvmgmt*mch-vpppfl*mch-ga|
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/kW2qS3/3)

To remove the `*` before the first `mch` value.

```
$ perl -pe 's/[^|]*?(\*mch-\w+).*?(?=\*mch|\|)/\1/g' file | sed 's/|\*/|/'
ghselm|Linka|Alzelmo|BJKSKJ|SK1234|mch-kminvmgmt*mch-kminvmgmt*mch-vpppfl*mch-ga|
```

Comment: Thanks. I got it right using below script.                             perl -pe 's/[^|]*?(\*mch-\w+).*?(?=\*mch|\|)/\1/g' file | sed 's/|\*/|/g'  > new_file